# jQuery, datePicker widget - Display disabled date in datePicker text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery 1.7.2, jQuery UI Datepicker Widget

In my Datepicker:
           Today and future dates are enabled
       Previous dates are disabled

I have a situation, where I need to display an old date in the text box but when the image is clicked the popup should have dates enabled from Today. Currently if the old date is 1Jun2014, today is getting displayed in the text box. How can I display 1Jun2014 in the text box and in the popup dates are enabled from today?

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#date-picker').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    minDate: 0, maxDate: "+11M",
    dateFormat:"d M y",
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "yymmdd"
});

var dispDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2014-06-01');
//$('#date-picker').datepicker('setDate', dispDate);

/* Updated code - begins */
var newDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yymmdd", dispDate);
var newDispDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("d M y", dispDate);
$('#date-picker').val(newDispDate);
$('#alternate').val(newDate);
/* Updated code - ends */

});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="date-picker" size="10" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="hidden" name="altDate" id="alternate"/>
```

**Update:**
    Based on Yashman Gupta's answer I updated the code, now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link below. The textbox takes the default value as some date and then when you click on the textbox, it will start from today's date. Hope this will work for you.

```
$(function () {
var currentDate = new Date();
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: currentDate,
    maxDate: "+1M +10D"
});
});

<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="06/05/2014">
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yashmangupta/p8J6d/1/

Comment: Put your code in your answer. If jsFiddle ever goes away, or can't be accessed, your answer becomes worthless.

Comment: @j08691 it seems there is no standard followed in the forum. Many people prefer to include JSFiddle while posting any solution or question. Anyways, I have posted the code.

Comment: @YashmanGupta Thanks for the hint, I modified my code. Please see my updated post.

Comment: A fiddle should accompany an answer when applicable, but should never take the place of code in the answer.